# Yodlee AddSiteAccount1 issues

Tags: yodlee

I am trying to verify various MFA based accounts Yodlee API by performing following steps:

1. Successful call to `addSiteAccount1`
2. In response, it does return `siteAccountId`
3. In response, it also provides site refresh status that `REFRESH_TRIGGERED`

   ```
   if resp['siteRefreshInfo']['siteRefreshMode']['refreshMode'] == 'MFA' and
      resp['siteRefreshInfo']['isMFAInputRequired'] == True and
      resp['siteRefreshInfo']['siteRefreshStatus']['siteRefreshStatus'] ==
      'REFRESH_TRIGGERED'
   ```
4. Now, calling `getMFAResponseForSite` repeatedly together with `getSiteRefreshInfo` results into initially code `801` and than `508` eventually timeout.
5. Eventually, I come out of the loop with result `isMessageAvailable: True`

   ```
     {u'itemId': 0, 
      u'retry': False, u'timeOutTime': 99880, u'memSiteAccId': 10144098,
      u'errorCode': 0, u'isMessageAvailable': True, u'fieldInfo':
      {u'questionAndAnswerValues': [], u'numOfMandatoryQuestions': -1,
      u'mfaFieldInfoType': u'SECURITY_QUESTION'}}
   ```

The only concern I have is that it provides `mfaFieldInfoType`, but it doesn't provide the actual question.

Couple questions:

a. How do I retrieve proper MFA question(s) for the site?

b. If user is initially coming into system and would like to link account more than couple second wait for user will kill the experience - so what's the recommended time period to be allowed to get MFA question?

c. Is this due to development vs. production environment difference?

d. I can retrieve account and holdings details for account, however than the account results in `NON_REFRESHABLE` state.

Answer (score 0):

After calling addSiteAccount1 API, you get siteAccountId for an account.
 Pass the siteAccountId to getMFAResponseForSite API and keep polling until you get the MFA form. then pass the MFA form with valid values to **putMFARequestForSite** API.

Please refer to our API flow- https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/API_Flow/Add_Site_Account

Blockquote

Sample response-

> {   "isMessageAvailable": true,   "fieldInfo": {
>       "questionAndAnswerValues": [
>         {
>           **"question": "What is the name of your state?",**
>           "questionFieldType": "label",
>           "responseFieldType": "text",
>           "isRequired": "true",
>           "sequence": 1,
>           "metaData": "QUESTION_1"
>         },
>         {
>           **"question": "What is the name of your first school",**
>           "questionFieldType": "label",
>           "responseFieldType": "text",
>           "isRequired": "true",
>           "sequence": 2,
>           "metaData": "QUESTION_2"
>         }
>       ],
>       "numOfMandatoryQuestions": 2,
>       "mfaFieldInfoType": "SECURITY_QUESTION"   },   "timeOutTime": 97340,   "itemId": 0,   "memSiteAccId": 10003775,   "retry": false }